Current in purely inductive circuit connected to dc circuit
So when there is no resistance and the battery is dc.. means no impedence at all.. The current can reach to a maximum  value of infinite.. means it can keep increasing and increasing....
Wt I imagine the situation is - current increases very fast  and inductor oppose it hence  no current  flows but current want to reach infinite so still it  is very high and Inductor still gets a potential equal and opposite to battery to stop it...  Am confused in this part... I mean how do  voltage varies in such scenario..
Why is potential of inductor equal to potential of battery ?? At every stage
Bcoz emf across  inductor is given by  -Ldi/dt
So  this value depends on di/dt why come it numerically equals to potential of battery at start..

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Main ques is like in last part... am describing  first how the circuit is working..  judge how i m describing is true or not


I imagine the situation is - current increases very fast

How fast the current increases depends on the inductance value of the inductor and the voltage applied by the battery. It could be fast, or it could be slow.
"Fast" and "slow" are also relative to other things in your system. In some systems (say a 50 Hz power system) something that takes a millisecond to change is very fast , and in others (a processor running at 4 GHz) it's very slow.

current want to reach infinite so still it is very high

The current will get to be very high if you wait for it to increase to whatever level you consider "very high". It won't be very high immediately after you apply the voltage.

I mean how do voltage varies in such scenario..

If you're assuming an ideal battery, then the voltage doesn't vary at all. An "ideal battery" means one whose output voltage doesn't change no matter how much current you draw from it.
If you use a real battery, the voltage will drop as the current increases due to the equivalent internal resistance of the battery, and this will mean that the current also doesn't increase indefinitely but instead asymptotically approaches a finite limit.

Why is potential of inductor equal to potential of battery ?

Because of Kirchhoff's Voltage Law. The potential drop from point A to point B (the two terminals of the inductor) is the same whether you take the path through the battery or the path through the inductor.

So this value depends on di/dt why come it numerically equals to potential of battery at start..

Because you connected the terminals of the battery to the terminals of the inductor.
To solve a circuit you don't just need to know the properties of the individual components. You also need to consider how those components are connected to each other.
